# Is the Dlib library free?

Tags: python, dlib

Is the Dlib library free? Because at the company we have plans to use it to recognize documents with Python.

Where can I find the Dlib license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's free. From the home page:

> Dlib's [open source licensing](http://dlib.net/license.html) allows you to use it in any application, free of charge.

Comment: I just have one question, does the license allow any company to use this library? I read the documentation, but I didn't understand it very well :/

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but it seems to be pretty clear that any person or organization is allowed.

Comment: [opensource.se] or [law.se] would probably be a better place to ask for detailed interpretation.